# Removing Element in ApplicationHost Config file

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to remove `centralBinaryLogFile` element from the applicationHost config file:

I am using the below to remove this:

```
 Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.applicationHost/log' -Name 'centralBinaryLogFile'
```

However, whenever it complains each time I try and remove it with the below:

```
**WARNING: Property centralBinaryLogFile is not found on  /system.applicationHost/log.**
```

I know it exists as if I run the below I get the element back fine:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.applicationHost/log' -Name 'centralBinaryLogFile'


enabled           : True
directory         : %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
period            : Daily
truncateSize      : 20971520
localTimeRollover : False
ItemXPath         : /system.applicationHost/log
Attributes        : {enabled, directory, period, truncateSize...}
ChildElements     : {}
ElementTagName    : centralBinaryLogFile
Methods           : 
Schema            : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

I also tried to use the below thinking a hash table might do the trick - but then it complains that Name is not a collection

```
Remove-WebconfigurationProperty -Filter "system.applicationHost/log" "Machine/WebRoot/AppHost" -Name centralBinaryLogFile -AtElement @{ElementTagName="centralBinaryLogFile"}
```

Any ideas how I remove this please?

Comment: You left out the code example of how you were trying to remove it.

Comment: yep - sorry, added it in now. I also tried another line at the bottom of the question as well - both not doing as I want unfortunately at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted the same thing and got the same behavior. I know it's not removing it, but will disabling suffice?

```
Set-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.applicationHost/log/centralBinaryLogFile' -value @{enabled=$false}
```

Comment: I found the answer in the end...it is not REMOVE-WEBCONFIGURATION....but CLEAR-WEBCONFIGURATION...Clear-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.applicationHost/log/centralBinaryLogFile'

Comment: how to remove IIS environment variable  by using remove-webconfigurationproperty

Answer (score 7):

In case someone else gets stuck and head is in a spin...do not use remove-webconfigurationproperty but CLEAR-WebConfiguration:

```
Clear-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.applicationHost/log/centralBinaryLogFile'
```